# How to upgrade from Next 13.2.4 to Next 13.3?

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js, next.js13

I recently got a popup in my Next.js project that says: `Next.js (13.2.4) out of date (learn more). There is a newer version (13.3.0), upgrade recommended!` I clicked the [learn more link](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/version-staleness) and ran the command to upgrade a non-canary version: `npm i next@latest`. When the installation was complete I got an error in the terminal:

```
npm WARN cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Users\\ekric\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\open-table-clone\\node_modules\\@next\\.swc-win32-x64-msvc-Ah4YEJy7',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\ekric\OneDrive\Desktop\open-table-clone\node_modules\@next\.swc-win32-x64-msvc-Ah4YEJy7\next-swc.win32-x64-msvc.node'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'unlink',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\ekric\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\open-table-clone\\node_modules\\@next\\.swc-win32-x64-msvc-Ah4YEJy7\\next-swc.win32-x64-msvc.node'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ]
npm WARN cleanup ]
```

And when I went back to work on my web app I got the same outdated popup. Here's my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "open-table-clone",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.15",
    "@prisma/client": "^4.11.0",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.1",
    "@types/node": "18.15.0",
    "@types/react": "18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.11",
    "@types/validator": "^13.7.14",
    "axios": "^1.3.5",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "jose": "^4.13.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "next": "^13.3.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.9.5",
    "validator": "^13.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prisma": "^4.11.0"
  }
}
```

In summary, my question is how can I update my Next 13 release?

Comment: Did u restart the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The is a bug in Next 13.3.0 the solution was to install a canary version by running `npm install next@canary`.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because of nextjs failed to load swc binary (`swc-win32-x64`). In order to fix this try the following:-

- If you are using `yarn`, then delete the `yarn.lock` file or if npm, then delete the `package-lock.json`.
- Completely delete your `node_modules` folder and reinstall the packages through your preferred package manager (`npm`/`yarn`).

```bash
npm install # or yarn install
```

---

If this doesn't work, then:

- `npm cache clean --force` before `npm install`, **especially if you upgraded to higher version of Node.js recently.**

Comment: Ok now in my ````package.json``` file I see ```"next": "^13.3.0",``` which is good but when I go to localhost:3000 I see a blank page. In my terminal, I see: ```error - SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)```

Comment: I think it is related to code you write, The swc issue should have been resolved.

Comment: It worked fine in Next 13.2.4

Comment: I have found two new issues on nextjs repo. check it out if the issue is the same. [issue#48052](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/48052) [issue#48177](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/48177)

Comment: No, I don't think those are applicable since they seem to apply to using ```yarn build``` or ````pnpm build``` whereas I'm using npm.  I've added more details to my question so please check those out.

Answer (score 0):

The `error - SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)` happens on components with a `use client`.

To solve it you need to convert your functions in that components from normal function () {} to arrow functions.

It's a bug that should be fixed in an upcoming update.